# Cannot add items to emptyObservableList "UnsupportedOperationException"

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to copy the contents of my `sql` table into an `ObservableList` so i implemented the following method which returns an `ObservableList<Article>` :

```
    public static ObservableList<Article> getArticles() throws SQLException {

        Connection con = conMenu.getCon();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from Article");

        ObservableList<Article> list = FXCollections.emptyObservableList();

        while(rs.next()){

 //create dummy article and set it's values to the current resultset row
            Article x = new Article();
            x.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            x.setName(rs.getString(2));
            x.setFamily(rs.getString(3));
            x.setSubFamily(rs.getString(4));
            x.setPrice(rs.getFloat(5));
// print sql table in console
            System.out.println(
                    rs.getInt(1)+" \t  "+
                    rs.getString(2)+"\t"+
                    rs.getString(3)+"\t"+
                    rs.getString(4)+"\t"+
                    rs.getString(5)+"\t"
                                            );
            list.add(x);
        }
        con.close();
return list ;
    }
```

At first i used a normal `ObservableList` but then there was an error when adding to it saying it's not `initialized`, and also it shouldnt be `null`.

Then, i declared an `emptyObservableList` to get around *that* but then i couldnt add items to it because it's an "UnsopportedOperationException" ??

Comment: `Creates an empty unmodifiable observable list.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc for `FXCollections.emptyObservableList()` is pretty clear:

> Creates an empty unmodifiable observable list.

You need a new, empty, but modifiable list:

```
ObservableList<Article> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```